# Transitivity of 1-to-1 functions

Tags: functions

If $g:A\rightarrow B$ and $f:B\rightarrow C$ are both 1 to 1, how do we prove that $f\circ g$ is 1-to-1?

What type of a proof method would be required exactly?

Comment: A general idea to keep in mind: in problems where the conclusion is similar to the hypothesis (like in your case) you can prove simply by writing down the definitions of what you want to prove and what you have, and just following your nose.

Answer (score 1):

To show $h : A \to C$ is one-to-one you need to show that **if** $h(a)=h(a')$ **then** $a=a'$.

Do this with $h = f \circ g$, using the fact that both $g$ and $f$ are one-to-one and that $(f \circ g)(x) = f(g(x))$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 1):

You want to show that **if** $(f\circ g)(a)=(f\circ g)(a')$ **then** $a=a'$.

So suppose that $(f\circ g)(a)=(f\circ g)(a')$.

Note that $(f\circ g)(a)=f(g(a))$. Similarly, $(f\circ g)(a')=f(g(a'))$.

If $f(g(a))=f(g(a))$, then, because $f$ is one to one, we have $g(a)=g(a')$. Now we are close to the end.

The proof could also be written up as a proof by contradiction. Suppose that $(f\circ g)(a)=(f\circ g)(a')$.  We show that $a=a'$. Suppose to the contrary that $a\ne a'$. Then $g(a)\ne g(a')$, since $g$ is one to one. But then $\dots$.

Which version we use is a matter of taste. The two versions are essentially the same.

Answer (score 1):

The proof method depends on your definition of what 1-to-1 function is, suppose for $a,b\in A$ that $a\neq b$, then the injectivity of $g$ gives you that $g(a)\neq g(b)$ and the injectivity of $f$ gives you that $f(g(a))\neq f(g(b))$, but this implies that $f\circ g$ is injective.

Answer (score 1):

If $f:A\to B$ is one-one so we know that: $$f(a)=f(b)\Longrightarrow a=b$$ First af all we see that $h=f\circ g:A\to C$ is a function as you noted and as you know this fact. Let $$h(a)=h(b)$$ then $$f\circ g(a)=f\circ g(b)$$ but $f$ is a one-one function so $$f\circ g(a)=f\circ g(b)\Longrightarrow g(a)=g(b)$$ but $g$ has the same property so, $$g(a)=g(b)\Longrightarrow a=b$$ Overall we reach to this: $$f\circ g(a)=f\circ g(b)\Longrightarrow g(a)=g(b)\Longrightarrow a=b$$ This means that $h$ is one-one function.